# Slack channel for Botpress v11

Tags: node.js, bots, slack

I'm trying the new version of Botpress but a lot of thing changes and I can't find any doc on how to add custom modules. Like I want to use Slack with the bot but the NPM module [@botpress/channel-slack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@botpress/channel-slack) doesn't seem to support this version (and copying the tarball directly in Botpress Server didn't work).

Is there a new way to add modules or are they just deprecated?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, Slack channel wasn't ported to Botpress 11 but support for it is planned soon in Botpress 12. The channel will most likely be backward compatible for botpress 11.

A proposal for module registry/configuration [has beed made](https://github.com/botpress/botpress/pull/1693) and is planned for development in botpress 12.